# Null space of $\mathbf{AB}$ given that $N(\mathbf{A})$ and $N(\mathbf{B})$ are trivial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ and we know $N(\mathbf{B}) = \left\{\mathbf{0}\right\}$ and $N(\mathbf{A}) = \left\{\mathbf{0}\right\}$, then does this also imply that $N(\mathbf{AB}) = \left\{\mathbf{0}\right\}$?

We know that $N(\mathbf{B}) \subseteq N(\mathbf{AB})$. Proving the converse, suppose $x \in N(\mathbf{AB})$. Then $\mathbf{ABx} = \mathbf{0}$. Since the null space of $\mathbf{A}$ is trivial, we must necessarily have $\mathbf{Bx} = \mathbf{0}$, implying that $N(\mathbf{AB}) \subseteq N(\mathbf{B})$. Thus, $N(\mathbf{AB}) = N(\mathbf{B}) = \left\{\mathbf{0}\right\}$. Any flaws in this argument?

Comment: No. Looks fine to me.

Comment: The composition of injective maps is injective. If you consider $f(x)=Bx$ and $g(x)=Ax$ (with the proper domains and codomains), $f$ and $g$ are injective and so also $g\circ f$ is. This just confirms your reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine. Note that you have shown that $N(A) = \{0\} \implies N(AB) = N(B)$ without using the assumption that $N(B) = \{ 0 \}$.